# Lightning Component in community builder: get recordId outside of v.body?

Tags: community, salesforcedx

I'm fairly new to SF so please bare with me.

The `force:hasRecordId` [interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation) provides a component with the `recordId` attribute. But only in record contexts and, as it seems, only if I drop the component in the content area (v.body of my custom theme layout component) of the community builder.

> These unsupported contexts include a few contexts that might seem like they should have access to the current record. Examples of these other contexts include the following:
>
> - Invoking the component from a global action (even when you’re on a
>     record page)
> - Invoking the component from header or footer navigation    in a
>     community (even if the page shows a record)

I also need the current `recordId` in my custom navigation component, which is placed in the sidebar area. The simpliefied code of my custom theme layout component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global">
 <aura:attribute name="sidebar" type="Aura.Component[]" />
 <div class="sidebar">{!v.sidebar}</div>
</aura:component>
```

The simplified code of my custom navigation component:

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase"
implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
access="global">
 <div>RecordId: {!v.recordId}</div>
</aura:component>
```

The problem is that in my navigation component, `recordId` is always empty. But I think I need it to mark the currently visited menu item.

Any clues how to solve this?